# Calling a function (containing variable) in another class

Tags: ios, swift, function, class, uiview

I have a relatively simple question. I created a function - covers the contents to retrieve data from the API. I need to call a function in several different classes (don't want to duplicate). I am calling that function, but nothing is getting displayed. If this function is a part of class where I want to call it, it works correctly. Where is the problem, please let me know. (I think in UIView...)? Thank you.

**My function:**

```
func loadScreen() {

        var loadView:UIView!

        loadView = UIView(frame: self.view.frame)
        loadView!.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
        loadView!.alpha = 1.0

        let actView = UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.gray)
        actView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 20, height: 20)
        actView.center = CGPoint(x: self.view.bounds.size.width / 2 , y: self.view.bounds.size.height / 2 )
        actView.startAnimating()

        loadView?.addSubview(actView)
        self.view.addSubview(loadView!)
    }
```

I call a function in another class in viewDidLoad (), but as I said, nothing is displayed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First create a singleton class like this**

[Singleton class](https://github.com/manish-1988/StackAnswers/blob/master/Singleton.swift)

```
  import UIKit
  import Foundation

class Singleton: NSObject
{
    static let sharedInstance = Singleton()

    override init()
    {
        super.init()
    }


    func placeBlockerView(target : UIViewController)
    {
        var loadView:UIView!
        loadView = UIView(frame: target.view.frame)
        loadView!.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
        loadView!.alpha = 1.0

        let actView = UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.gray)
        actView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 20, height: 20)
        actView.center = CGPoint(x: target.view.bounds.size.width / 2 , y: target.view.bounds.size.height / 2 )
        actView.startAnimating()

        loadView?.addSubview(actView)
        target.view.addSubview(loadView!)
    }
}
```

After that use it from where ever you want as required

like this

```
Singleton.sharedInstance.placeBlockerView(target: self)
```

This above line will add that UIView you have created to your view controller's view.

Let me know if it don't work.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding it in the above, it is always advised to `return the UIView` from that method and in your subclass of `UIViewController` do the following.

```
func viewDidLoad() {
     let loadView = loadScreen()
     self.view.addSubView()
}
```